# Julia - build windows standalone executable?

Tags: windows, build, compilation, julia

We have a Julia code that is processing data for our users and display results.
I need to build/compile it to Windows executable as the users (financial analysts) have very limited IT knowledge, they cannot use Julia, the work environment is remote and they cannot install Julia, they don't know how to use .jl files, command line etc. It needs something very simple, an executable, binary, easy to distribute and use.
I tried the package compiler it seems not possible to build for Win32/64 standalone with all dependencies included, couldn't create something useful and easy to distribute.
Please help. Tx.

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad a question to be sensibly answered on SO, and it's also pretty much impossible to answer unless you can provide some more detail about what exactly went wrong. I'd suggest you read https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/apps/ again in detail, and then either edit your question here to include more detail or maybe ask on the Julia Discourse which imho works better for this type of question.

Comment: For your scenario (remote work environment, nontechnical users, complex project) perhaps the best thing would be to publish your code as a web service and build the GUI with JavaSctipt/Angular and make the whole thing accessible via a web browser.

Comment: Sorry not being explicit: I am not an Julia expert, the code was delivered from a 3rd party contractor before Covid crisis, now we need to use it, distribute it to our analysts for processing results. We lack a proper IT development support (due the current situation), so I have to handle it myself, in a short time. I was looking for a proper/concise tutorial something like "How to compile to Windows executabile a Julia program - step by step" but couldn't find something as such.  The PackageCompler stuff is very indecipherable for someone who is not really into Julia programming.

Comment: More precisely, from  myApp.jl to myApp.exe. I don't understand why should be so difficult...

Comment: Which packages your app depends from ("using..."). As others have told you, you would be better off to ask this kind of question in the Julia discourse forum..

Comment: AnimatedPlots, Econometrics, FinanceStats, BasicSpace,  DataFrames, JSON, csv, Distributions, Sampling, Turing, DiffModel, MathToolkit, FileIO, Judo, EChart, Ito, ZVSimulator, Caching, lpopt, StatsBase, Events, DataRead, etc.    Please, don't ask me internals of the code because, I repeat,  I am not a Julia developer, the code was made externally.